# New magento instance 404 error

Tags: apache, mamp

I have couple of instances configured in my httpd file to run multiple magento store. Now problem has arise, i wanted to install new magento install but after setup, and going to either back end or front end. I am given 404 error, which wasn't helpful. so i ran

```
apachectl -t
```

and i got this error

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.10. Set the 'ServerName'
>   directive globally to suppress this message Syntax OK

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    # allow fonts to be displayed on the blogs
    <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>

    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE 'website'
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE 'alpha'
    SetEnv MAGE_SET_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/alpha/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/beta"
    ServerName dev.beta.com
    ServerAlias dev.beta.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    # allow fonts to be displayed on the blogs
    <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>

    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE 'website'
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE 'go'
    SetEnv MAGE_SET_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/beta">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think i have lost the setting for default localhost and i tried to copy wrong way to reach localhost. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `AH00558` referencing that your apache can't resolve one of hostnames declared in `ServerName`, propably `dev.beta.com`.

Which host stands for the `192.168.0.10` ip ?

Also, for your first `VirtualHost` localhost you have `DocumentRoot`  set as `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` considering your configuration, you probably meant `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/alpha` as you provided it in the `Directory`.

Comment: `192.168.0.10` refers to localhost, providing me list of sites (folders) i have in my htdocs. i am lost with the localhost `VirtualHost` as i try to replicate what is suppose to be a default setting to read localhost just like after default conf will be upon installing apache. The `dev.beta.com` also give 404 error, but it is a different store in my magento install.

Comment: In which directory you have your first magento instance  files and in which directory you have your second magento instance files ? Is it 404 from webserver of from magento ?

Comment: first instance is in localhost/chorme which is a new fresh install, the `alpha` and `beta` are same instance but different stores.  The 404 on beta is magento 404, as per theme design.

Comment: please make sql query on you 404 instance database `select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';` and show output, compare it with your actual url that should return your magento install

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?724be78e1adf702f#YDkaFUhRHxOJ3rwKdrShxqVGMaPLEcHNvzgDCFM133k=) is the output

Comment: so, what you put in you address field in your browser when you try to open `http://dev.alpha.com/` and `http://dev.beta.com/`, are they both in your `/etc/hosts` files ? if so, you have to change `ServerName localhost` to `ServerName dev.alpha.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38491/discussion-between-nofel-and-anonymous).